# Using wget on a directory

Tags: linux, shell

I'm fairly new to shell and I'm trying to use wget to download a .zip file from one directory to another. The only file in the directory I am copying the file from is the .zip file. However when I use wget IP address/directory it downloads an index.html file instead of the .zip. Is there something I am missing to get it to download the .zip without having to explicitly state it?

Comment: If you want to download the zip file you have to provide the URL of the zip file itself (e.g., `http://example.com/somedirectory/myfile.zip`).

Comment: consider editing your question to show the exact command you are issuing, and then use `/bin/ls -l ` in the receiving directory to show what has received. Otherwise, we're just guessing. Use the `{}` tool to format code-like text so the text will not wrap into one big paragraph. Good luck.

Comment: Kindly post the wget command you're executing.

Answer (score 0):

[wget](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.htm) is the utility to download file from web.

you have mentioned you want to copy from one directory to other. you meant it is on same server/node?
In that case you can simply use [cp](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_cp.htm) command

And if you want if from any other server/node [file transfer] you can use [scp](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_scp.htm) or [ftp](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ftp.htm)